# email attachments viewed as downloadable links

Tags: php, email, attachment

I tried to follow several tutorials about making a PHP contact form with attachments but I found them quite complex, whilst I'm searching for a simple solution with really a few lines of code. Hoping in some help from this forum.

The only thing I have right now is the browse button code:

```
<label class="solo" for='attachment'>BROWSE</label><input name="attachment" id="attachment" type="file"/>
```

I just need the attachments to be uploaded into a folder and be able to see/download them with a link in the email I get from users.  Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

If the basic tutorials seem too complicated for you, I highly recommend checking out any of the paid uploader scripts at codecanyon.net.

PHP Form File Uploading isn't an easy/simple thing to do. It takes a lot of understanding of PHP and your server configuration, a lot of testing, and a lot of stress. I highly recommend just buying a PHP uploader script.

Answer (score 0):

I pinned down the following code for attaching a file:

`$allowedExts = array("jpeg", "doc", "pdf", "zip", "rar");
    $temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
    $extension = end($temp);
    if ((((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
    || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpg")
    || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")
    || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "application/doc")
    || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "application/docx")
    || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "application/pdf"))
    || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "application/zip"))
    || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "application/rar"))
    && ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 20000)
    && in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
    {
        if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
          {
          echo "Error: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
          }
        else
          {
          echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
          echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
          echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " Kb<br>";
          echo "Stored in: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
          }
        if (file_exists("attachments/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
          {
          echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
          }
        else
          {
          move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
          "attachments/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
          echo "Stored in: " . "attachments_folder/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
          }
    }
    else
      {
      echo "Invalid file";
      }`

Now I need to include a text in the message with a download link to attachments_folder. I'd appreciate some help as my knowledge of PHP is zero. :)